# Latex mode: tex-verbatim face has priority on font-lock-comment-face

Tags: latex, customize-face

I switched to Emacs 29.1 recently.

I noticed that the `tex-verbatim` face used in `latex-mode` to highlight the `\href` argument has priority on `font-lock-comment-face`.

[image: img]

The `tex-verbatim` face is defined in `tex-mode.el`:

```el
(defface tex-verbatim
  '((t :inherit fixed-pitch-serif))
  "Face used to highlight TeX verbatim environments."
  :group 'tex)
```

How can I fix this face, in my `.emacs` file, to make `font-lock-comment-face` has priority on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the value of the font-lock-keywords variable and found:

```el
("\\\(ProvidesFile\|href\|nolinkurl\|path\|url\) \(\[[^]]\] \){\(\(?:[^{}\]\|\\.\|{[^}]}\)+\)" 3 'tex-verbatim t)
```

If I remove the fontification with:

```el
(font-lock-remove-keywords 
 nil 
 '(("\\\\\\(ProvidesFile\\|href\\|nolinkurl\\|path\\|url\\) *\\(\\[[^]]*\\] *\\)*{\\(\\(?:[^{}\\]\\|\\\\.\\|{[^}]*}\\)+\\)" 
    3 'tex-verbatim t)))

(font-lock-flush)
```

and run this command to add fontification:

```el
(font-lock-add-keywords 
 nil 
 '(("\\\\\\(ProvidesFile\\|href\\|nolinkurl\\|path\\|url\\) *\\(\\[[^]]*\\] *\\)*{\\(\\(?:[^{}\\]\\|\\\\.\\|{[^}]*}\\)+\\)"
    3 'tex-verbatim keep)))

(font-lock-flush)
```

the problem disappears.

The manual says:

> The last two values in subexp-highlighter, override and laxmatch, are
> optional flags. If override is t, this element can override existing
> fontification made by previous elements of font-lock-keywords. If it
> is keep, then each character is fontified if it has not been fontified
> already by some other element. If it is prepend, the face specified by
> facespec is added to the beginning of the font-lock-face property. If
> it is append, the face is added to the end of the font-lock-face
> property.

So I think that `keep` should be the right choice.

I submitted a bug report.