# Determining AUCTeX Activation in Emacs Buffer: Major Mode Detection Issue

Tags: latex, auctex

I recently upgraded to Emacs 29.1 (from Emacs 26).

While using `latex-mode`, I encountered a fontification issue for which I found a patch ([Latex mode: tex-verbatim face has priority on font-lock-comment-face](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/80201/15606)). I also observed that this issue does not occur with `AUCTeX`.

My setup includes having `AUCTeX` installed but not activated by default when editing `.tex` files. I prefer the default `latex-mode` (AUCTeX does not provide its own major mode but overrides it [How to install AUCTeX on Emacs without automatic activation for LaTeX (.tex) files?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/80250/15606)).

My question is: unable to use the `major-mode` variable, which has the same value for both the standard `latex-mode` and `AUCTeX`, and assuming that `AUCTeX` is installed on my machine anyway, how do I test whether `AUCTeX` (potentially activated by the `TeX-latex-mode` function) is active in the buffer?

The only clue I have is that on my machine, I see "LaTeX" on the mode-line when the default `latex-mode` is active, while if I activate `AUCTeX` (`M-x TeX-latex-mode`), the lighter is "LaTeX/P".

My goal is to apply the patch only when the default `latex-mode` is active in the buffer and NOT `AUCTeX`.

Answer (score 2):

From `mode-line-format` we find that the "LaTeX/P" in the mode-line is configured via `mode-line-modes`. From there we find that "LaTeX/P" is simply the value of `mode-name` so you could check if AUCTeX is active by checking the mode-name:

```lisp
(string= mode-name "LaTeX/P")
```

Furthermore, from looking at the code of `TeX-set-mode-name` we find that the "P" is due to `TeX-PDF-mode`, but other modes are possible. Therefore I guess a more universal check is to check that the mode-name is not "LaTeX"

```lisp
(not (string= mode-name "LaTeX"))
```

Comment: I often find myself wishing that AUCTeX had done things differently and not done a land grab on `latex-mode` etc. But I guess it's too late now.

Comment: @NickD - It is never too late, and wishes do come true `:-)` Next AUCTeX release  changes the mode names and leaves `latex-mode` alone.  Check [this announcement](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex-devel/2024-01/msg00002.html) for details

Comment: @NickD I am not sure in what way. It seems quite natural to me that it 'extends/hijacks' latex-mode. It does it cleanly by (:override) advising latex-mode. I'm no heavy latex user (at least not at the moment), but I guess AUCTeX design is 99% of the cases not a 'big deal'. It might be too late to 'fix' the design with the advice, but it should not be too much work to add a (better) AUCTeX indicator, and update its documentation about its 'relation' to latex-mode.

Comment: The second part of the answer leaves me with some doubt. What happens if no additional modes are activated? In that case, mode-name would simply be "LaTeX". I also think that `AUCTeX` should be structured as a standalone major mode even though it is derived from `latex-mode`. In the `latex.el` code, I see the comment: "FIXME: Use `define-derived-mode'." so I believe the developers are aware of it."

Comment: Not sure, but I guess that when using AUCTeX, probably always one of those modes is active. I have quickly tried to confirm it from looking at the code of `TeX-set-mode-name`, and although it looks like it's the case, I am not sure. What I do find, is that AUCTeX uses the variable `TeX-mode-p`. So I guess that variable is non-nil when AUCTeX is active, and nil when it is not (but, I'm not sure about it). Despite their comment, I don't see, if things work fine, why AUCTeX should be a different mode, as one can use only a single major-mode at a time. Good documentation is important though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run `advice-member-p` and test for the advice on `latex-mode`:

> advice-member-p is a native-compiled Lisp function in ‘nadvice.el’.
>
> (advice-member-p ADVICE SYMBOL)
>
> Return non-nil if ADVICE has been added to SYMBOL. Instead of ADVICE
> being the actual function, it can also be the ‘name’ of the piece of
> advice.

So something like this should return non-nil when AUCTeX is activated:

```el
(advice-member-p #'TeX-latex-mode #'latex-mode)
```

Comment: I tried your code but I get `nil` in both cases,